# How can I compile a string supplied on the command line during compilation into my Rust binary?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to make it so that when my program starts it prints to stderr:

```
This is Program X v. 0.1.0 compiled on 20180110. Now listening on stdin,
quit with SIGINT (^C). EOF is ignored. For licensing  information,  read 
LICENSE. To suppress this message, supply --quiet or --suppress-greeting
```

In C/C++, I would achieve this with a Makefile, e.g.:

```
VERSION = 0.1.0
FLAGS = -Wall -pipe -O3 -funroll-loops -Wall -DVERSION="\"$(VERSION)\"" -DCOMPILED_AT="\"`date +%Y%m%d`\""
```

Then, in the source code, I would use those constants as I pleased, perhaps in a call to `fprintf`. After checking if they actually existed with `#ifdef`, of course.

How can this be achieved in Rust? Do I need to use a procedural macro? Can I use `cargo` somehow?

I know that `env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION")` can be used as a replacement for `VERSION`, but what about `COMPILED_AT`?

Comment: I recommend NOT tracking timestamps of the build time.  See https://reproducible-builds.org/docs/timestamps/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

## Use a `build.rs` script

The benefit of using a `build.rs` script is that other users compiling your program will not have to invoke `cargo` in a special way or set up their environment. Here is a minimal example of how to do that.

### `build.rs`

```
use std::process::{Command, exit};
use std::str;

static CARGOENV: &str = "cargo:rustc-env=";

fn main() {
    let time_c = Command::new("date").args(&["+%Y%m%d"]).output();

    match time_c {
        Ok(t) => {
            let time;
            unsafe {
                time = str::from_utf8_unchecked( &t.stdout );
            }   
            println!("{}COMPILED_AT={}", CARGOENV, time);
        }   
        Err(_) => exit(1)
    }   
}
```

### `src/main.rs`

```
fn main() {
    println!("This is Example Program {} compiled at {}", env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION"), env!("COMPILED_AT"));
}
```

### `Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "compiled_at"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Fredrick Brennan <copypaste@kittens.ph>"]
build = "build.rs"

[dependencies]
```

Obviously this can be tweaked to get it to work on other platforms which don't have a `/bin/date` or to compile in other things such as the Git version number. This script was based on the example provided by Jmb, which shows how to add Mercurial information into your program at compile time.

This guarantees that `COMPILED_AT` will either be set or the build will fail. This way other Rust programmers can build just by doing `cargo build`.

```
[osboxes@osboxes compiled_at]$ cargo run
   Compiling compiled_at v0.1.0 (file:///home/osboxes/Workspace/rust/compiled_at)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.27 secs
     Running `target/debug/compiled_at`
This is Example Program 0.1.0 compiled at 20180202
```

## Use `env!()`, then require users to set their environment prior to building

It occurred to me after I asked this question to try the following, and it does work (`vim` is in use, thus the escaped `%`s), `cargo` does pass my environment down to `rustc`:

```
COMPILED_AT=`date +\%Y\%m\%d` cargo run
```

Then, in Rust:

```
fn main() {
    eprintln!("{}", env!("COMPILED_AT"));
}
```

The Rust compiler refuses to compile the code if I don't supply the environment variable, which is a nice touch.

```
error: environment variable `COMPILED_AT` not defined
   --> src/main.rs:147:21
    |
147 |     eprintln!("{}", env!("COMPILED_AT"));
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

This way is extremely hacky and is guaranteed to annoy other Rust programmers who just expect to build with `cargo build`, but it does work. If you can, it is recommended to use the `build.rs` instead.

Comment: I think you could do this in a [script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html), you can see the [list](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fbf50cc18cece4c4f01c1f38cb51f68f&version=stable) of all env variable, and cargo documentation [list](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html) some. But currently cargo don't define a environnement variable for compile date, you could ask it on the github to add this feature but I not sure it's will be accepted.

Comment: Very interesting, from my reading of those pages perhaps my `build.rs` could call `date +%Y%m%d` and put its output on the command line like `cargo:rustc-env=COMPILED_AT=20180110`...

Comment: call date... or use [chrono](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono) in the build.rs ;)

Comment: @Stargateur: I'd rather have the ability to supply custom variables than a hardcoded "COMPILED_AT" one :)

Comment: I really think that rather than looking at a custom invocation of `cargo` or a script over cargo, you should look into `build.rs`. The intent of `build.rs` is specifically to "script" the build so that creating a Rust project is always the same command (`cargo build`). This uniformity is what makes integrating 3rd party dependencies so painless, it should not be discarded without really good reasons :)

Comment: If you don't want the build to fail just because the environment variable is missing, use [`option_env!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.option_env.html) instead of `env!`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `build.rs` script to add an environment variable to the cargo environment or to create an extra source file that contains the information you need. That way you can add a lot of information about the build environment. Here is a [full example](https://bitbucket.org/jmb/rnbench/src/887f6f4fcf204f8e55f351ea51bffc39aec26eb5/build.rs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) that creates a `build_info.rs` source file containing:

- Version information built from the Mercurial tag, revision hash and status (including the date if the source folder is different from the Mercurial folder).
- Toolchain information, including the compiler version and the build profile (eg. `debug` or `release`) thanks to the `rustc_version` crate.
- Plus it extracts some information from cargo (like the package name) so it doesn't have to be duplicated between the `Cargo.toml` and the source code).

---

```
#[macro_use] extern crate map_for;
extern crate rustc_version;
extern crate time;

use rustc_version::{ Channel, version_meta };
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::env;
use std::ffi::OsStr;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, Write};
use std::process::Command;

/// Run mercurial with the given arguments and return the output.
fn run_hg<S: AsRef<OsStr>> (args: &[S]) -> Option<String> {
   Command::new ("hg")
      .env ("HGRCPATH", "")
      .env ("LANG", "C")
      .args (args)
      .output()
      .ok()
      .and_then (|output|
                 String::from_utf8 (output.stdout)
                 .ok())
}

/// Get the version from a mercurial repository.
///
/// Version  numbers  follow the  Python  PEP440  conventions. If  the
/// current folder corresponds to a version tag, then return that tag.
/// Otherwise, identify  the closest  tag and return  a string  of the
/// form _tag_.dev_N_+_hash_. In both cases, if the current folder has
/// been  modified, then  add the  current date  as `YYYYMMDD`  to the
/// local version label.
fn get_mercurial_version_tag() -> Option<String> {
   let output = run_hg (&[ "id", "-i", "-t" ]);
   let mut iter = output.iter().flat_map (|s| s.split_whitespace()).fuse();
   let hash = match iter.next() {
      Some (hash) => hash,
      _ => { return None },
   };

   let clean = !hash.ends_with ("+");

   fn mkdate() -> String { time::strftime ("%Y%m%d", &time::now()).unwrap() }

   map_for!(
      version <- iter.find (|s| s.chars().next()
                            .map (|c| ('0' <= c) && (c <= '9'))
                            .unwrap_or (false));
         // The current folder corresponds to a version tag (i.e. a
         // tag that starts with a digit).
         => (if clean { version.into() }
             else { format!("{}+{}", version, mkdate()) }))
      .or_else (|| {
         // The current folder does not correspond to a version tag.
         // Find the closest tag and build the version from that. Note
         // that this may return a wrong version number if the closest
         // tag is not a version tag.
         let version = run_hg (
            &[ "parents",
                "--template",
                "{latesttag}.dev{latesttagdistance}+{node|short}" ]);
         if clean { version }
         else { version.map (|s| format!("{}.{}", s, mkdate())) }
      })
}

/// Get the version from Mercurial archive information.
///
/// The   Mercurial   `archive`   command   creates   a   file   named
/// `.hg_archival.txt`  that contains  information about  the archived
/// version. This function  tries to use this information  to create a
/// version string  similar to what  `get_mercurial_version_tag` would
/// have created for this version.
fn get_mercurial_archived_version_tag() -> Option<String> {
   use map_for::FlatMap;

   // Parse the contents of `.hg_archival.txt` into a hash map.
   let info = &File::open (".hg_archival.txt")
      .iter()
      .flat_map (|f| BufReader::new (f).lines())
      .filter_map (|l| l.ok())
      .map (|l| l.splitn (2, ':')
            .map (String::from)
            .collect::<Vec<_>>())
      .filter_map (
         |v| if v.len() == 2
         { Some ((String::from (v[0].trim()),
                  String::from (v[1].trim()))) }
         else { None })
      .collect::<HashMap<_,_>>();
   // Extract version information from the hash map.
   map_for!(
      tag <- info.get ("tag");
      => format!("{}+archive.{}", tag, time::strftime ("%Y%m%d", &time::now()).unwrap()))
      .or_else (|| map_for!{
         tag      <- info.get ("latesttag");
         distance <- info.get ("latesttagdistance");
         node     <- info.get ("node");
         => format!("{}.dev{}+archive.{:.12}.{}",
                    tag, distance, node,
                    time::strftime ("%Y%m%d", &time::now()).unwrap()) })
      .map (String::from)
}

/// Get the version information.
///
/// This function will  first try to get the version  from a Mercurial
/// repository. If that  fails, it will try to get  the version from a
/// `.hg_archival.txt` file. If both fail, it will return a version of
/// the form: "unknown-date".
fn get_version() -> String {
   get_mercurial_version_tag()
      .or_else (get_mercurial_archived_version_tag)
      .unwrap_or_else (
         || format!("{}+cargo.{}",
                    env::var ("CARGO_PKG_VERSION").unwrap(),
                    time::strftime ("%Y%m%d", &time::now()).unwrap())
            .into())
}

fn main()
{
   let mut f = File::create ("src/build_info.rs").unwrap();

   let version = version_meta().unwrap();
   writeln!(f, "pub const RUST_VERSION: &'static str = \"{} {} v{}\";",
            env::var ("RUSTC").unwrap_or ("rustc".into()),
            match version.channel {
               Channel::Dev => "dev",
               Channel::Nightly => "nightly",
               Channel::Beta => "beta",
               Channel::Stable => "stable",
            },
            version.semver).unwrap();
   writeln!(f, "pub const PROFILE: &'static str = \"{}\";",
            env::var ("PROFILE").unwrap_or ("unknown".into()))
      .unwrap();
   writeln!(f, "pub const TARGET: &'static str = \"{}\";",
            env::var ("TARGET").unwrap_or ("unknown".into()))
      .unwrap();
   writeln!(f, "pub const PKG_NAME: &'static str = \"{} {} {}\";",
            env::var ("CARGO_PKG_NAME").unwrap(),
            get_version(),
            env::var ("PROFILE").unwrap_or ("".into()))
      .unwrap();
   writeln!(f, "pub const PKG_VERSION: &'static str = \"{}\";",
            get_version())
      .unwrap();
}
```

Comment: I think your example don't need so much feature. One simple working environnement variable is enough.